# how to color the output for two different strings in two different files in Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, file-io

I have two files that will always hold different strings, I want to know a way to print out everything in those two files and highlight only the differences between them.

```
$cat file1.txt
fox:1
bike:3
beer:21

$cat file2.txt
fox:1
beer:22
bike:3

$pr -m -t file1.txt file2.txt
fox:1                         fox:1
beer:21                       bike:3
bike:3                        beer:22
```

I want `beer:21` `beer:22` to be highlighted in red. keep in mind that `beer`string is not always there in one of the files or existed but in a different name like `apple:0`

Comment: Do you want us to reinvent `diff`?

Comment: Diff will output only the difference between the two files, and I want the difference highlighted along with he rest of the output. Correct me if I’m wrong

Comment: Sure. And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried `diff` on this operation because the output is now what I want..

Comment: Nope, I haven't found the solution yet

Comment: Maybe this is what you want : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79135/is-there-a-condensed-side-by-side-diff-format

Comment: Perhaps just use `diff -y`?

Comment: A method for coloring diff's output is given in this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196565/how-to-color-diff-output

Comment: both answers above didn't work, due to the system I have is not allowed me to install `icdiff` , same to `diff -y` also the output remained the same color.

Comment: Actually, not a programming question. OT.

Comment: What does OT mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `diff` and set color for changed lines:

```
diff --old-group-format=$'\e[0;31m%<\e[0m' 
     --new-group-format=$'\e[0;31m%>\e[0m'      
     --unchanged-group-format=$'\e[0;32m%=\e[0m'    file1 file2
```

Comment: I tried that, but can I make it side by side? Because the -y doesn’t work with this, do you know to?